# Run Command Instructions to open and save excel file

Tags: alteryx, runcommand

I am using the run command.  It starts with 
Start Excel.exe "Filepath\FileName.xls"
This opens the file.  A popup appears, and asks if you would like to update the links.
I need to know what commands in the run commands to use that would:

Tab and select "Don't Update", then save and close the file.
(this will be refreshing data that was just input into the file from Alteryx)
Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to do this [altering the Excel settings](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2099-excel-disable-update-links-prompt.html#a2), this is outside of the command line.